# IOS UIConstant declaration and calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I have created a Constant.h file
that contains following code

```
#ifndef myapp_Constants_h
#define myapp_Constants_h

#define cancel_bt @"cancel.png"

#endif
```

How can I call `cancel_btn` image as button image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `#define` does for you is to create a macro that gets replaced at compile time.

If you `#import` your `Constant.h` file at the top of a second file, any time the string occurs in that second file, the preprocessor will replace it with the string `@"cancel.png"`.

So if you add code that loads a image into a button, you could use `cancel_bt` as an image name instead of `@"cancel.png"`

From your question it sounds like you don't know how to replace a button's image through code. You want to use the UIButton method `setImage:forState:`. See the docs for more info on using it.

Answer (score 0):

just Import your **Constants.h** file,where you need.

```
#import "Constants.h"
```